# Neighboring Zipcodes from State Polygons

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf, r-sp, spdep

**First time posting on SO**

I have a shapefile that has the geometries for each Zipcode along with state name. I want to figure out which zipcodes lie on the state borders.
The way I figured to achieve this is by combining all zipcodes for each state and leading to the geometry for a state and then finding the neighboring zipcodes for each state.

I combined the zipcodes into states using:

`state_shape <- shapefile %>% group_by(State) %>% summarise(geometry = sf::st_union(geometry))`

But then when I try to find the neighboring zipcodes using `poly2nb`

`state_nb <- poly2nb(st_geometry(state_shape))`

It gives me an *Error*:

`Error in poly2nb(st_geometry(state_shape)) : Polygon geometries required`

I understand to find the border zipcodes I will have to pass the zipcode geometries in poly2nb, but the error persists.

Any help will be highly appreciated, also any other approaches to this problem are more than welcome.

Comment: Imagine you were trying to provide help to somebody. Would it be helpful if you could run their code? I guess my point is that you'll probably get more help if you provide the data and libraries you are using so that somebody can run your code and debug it.

Comment: The data is basically a .shp file. First column is the zipcode, the next is the name of the state to which the zipcode belongs to and the third column is the geometry of the zipcode. 

Libraries I'm using are sf, dplyr, rgeos and geosphere

Comment: So it is hard to know without a reproducible example. But `state_shape <- shapefile %>% group_by(State) %>% summarise(geometry = sf::st_union(geometry))` looks to me like you are summarizing by State. So, I presume you don't have county level information.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example, built on the widely available North Carolina shapefile that is distributed with {sf} package.

What the example does is:

- creates a border line of North Carolina by first dissolving the counties, and then casting the resulting multipolygon to a multilinestring
- runs `sf::st_touches()` on the counties and borderline with sparse set to false; the result is a logical vector that can be used to subset the original shapefile (filtering out the counties that share a border with the NC border)
- presents the results in a graphical format, using {ggplot2}; the bordering counties are blue and the rest just blank for context

  ```
    library(sf)
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)

    # all NC counties (from shapefile distributed with {sf})
    shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) 

    # border, via dplyr::summarise() & cast as a linestring
    border <- shape %>% 
      summarise() %>% 
      st_cast("MULTILINESTRING")

    # logical vector of length nrow(shape)
    neighbours <- sf::st_touches(shape,
                                 border,
                                 sparse = F)
    # report results
    ggplot() +
      geom_sf(data = shape[neighbours, ], fill = "blue") + # border counties
      geom_sf(data = shape, fill = NA, color = "grey45") # all counties for context
  ```

[image]